# Use custom Color in SolidColorBrush

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ResourceDictionary where I have defined some custom colors:

```
<Color x:Key="BMWhite">White</Color>
<Color x:Key="BMRed">Red</Color>
```

These new colors I want to use in at `SolidBrush` :

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ApplicationBackgroundColor1" Color="BMWhite"/>
```

But it is not a valid syntax (so VSS says).

Can this be done some how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try like this.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ApplicationBackgroundColor1" Color="{StaticResource BMWhite}"/>
```